# Undeclared Identifier Won't Go Away

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched on Stack Overflow for 6 hours straight but I still can't solve my problem. It says I have an undeclared identifier when I clearly identified in the .h file. It just keeps doing this and doing this and doing this. No matter what I do.

In the .h file I have

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

and in the .m file I have

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
```

Comment: I bet I can run circles around you in PS. Everyone has strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: show whole error message. and show more about your .h and .m file.

Comment: Ugh, I need 10 credits so it can make my life easier and just post a screenshot.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you've declared the variable in ProfileViewController but are trying to use it in AuthenticationViewController.

Comment: Thanks Anna! I think that's another problem I have with my code.

Comment: BTW - the cause of your original problem was because the you declared `imagePicker` as an ivar for the `ProfileViewController` class but you were trying to use it in a method of the `AuthenticationViewController` class. Why did you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, instance variable are declared in a the .m file. In the .h you declare the properties. So you should have something like this:

```
@implementation MyClass{
    UIImagePickerController *_imagePicker;
    ....
}
```

If you need it to be a public variable, declare it as a property in the .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

Comment: please, prefix your instance variable wit underscore. i.e. `_imagePicker`

Comment: That did the trick... Wow. Sorry for wasting everyone's time for something really simple.

Thanks

Comment: It sucks to be new around here, i know :D